# iMac not letting me downgrade to mavericks via USB

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imac, usb, downgrade

I already asked this question but because I didn't sign up it won't let me respond to anyone, but here it is again *with more info.

I made the mistake of installing Yosemite without backing up my HDD. Fortunately, I do have most of my actual files and programs saved to my external HDD, but that leads to another problem.

I use a lot of 3rd party apps to make music, and they are not compatible with 10.10 i.e. Pro Tools etc. I formatted my HDD in an attempt to start over but it keeps reinstalling Yosemite from the Internet.

I've made several USB boot drives but when they go to load up it just gives me "international no" sign (see image below).

Can someone *please* help me as my work/life is tied in to my studio. Oh also my external HDD is now all of a sudden read-only NTFS instead of Mac read/write enabled.

*****I made the USB several different times using first an app that was recomended and the second time using disk utility and the restore option with the dmg as my source and the usb as my destination...  I also tried several different versions of mavericks.  PLEASE HELP.

[image: Screenshot of OS X when cannot boot off of a USB]